# Using URL Routing for Web Forms with .ashx files

Tags: c#, .net

I am developing a .NET 3.5 Web Forms based website that uses URL Routing.  So far I have created a few routes and I have had no issue.  I now have a .ashx file that is going to handle sending .pdf files from a table in SQL Server to the website when someone clicks on a link.  Normally when I create a Handler it would look like this:

```
return BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath("~/ViewItem.aspx", typeof(Page)) as Page;
```

For my .ashx file I tried:

```
return BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath("~/FileServer.ashx", typeof(Page)) as Page;
```

This doesn't work though because fileserver.ashx is not a page so casting it as typeof(Page)) as Page is going to fail.  What do I cast the VirtualPath as instead of Page or is there some other way I should be doing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `typeof(IHttpHandler)` instead of `typeof(Page)`

That is the base class of the ashx file  Also change the return type from as Page to as IHttpHandler.  Then update any other code that depends on it being a page.

Answer (score 1):

It's an HTTP Handler, so you probably could use its IHttpHandler interface type to cast.  But you can't use page; you have to use the type the handler inherits from.